# How to handle UTF16 warning in Perl Mechanize call

Tags: perl, utf-16, www-mechanize

I get error while making mechanize call to websites having utf16 characters using mechanize in perl. It shows me this warning `Parsing of undecoded UTF-16 at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 600` I know that this is generated when I call $mech->content() method. Is there a way to ignore these warnings in content method of mechanize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could ignore warnings like this:

```
{
  no warnings;
  #your code that generate false warnings

};
```

You could solve the encoding errors with this, it may works.

> WWW::Mechanize is a proper subclass of LWP::UserAgent and you can also use any of LWP::UserAgent's methods.

```
my $content = $mech->decoded_content();#
if (utf8::is_utf8($content)) {
    binmode STDOUT,':utf8';
} else {
    binmode STDOUT,':raw';
}
print $content;
```

Comment: Second approach works for me. Ignoring warning will affect other function for which I need the warnings also.

Comment: The ignore warnings this way is localized to the closures. You could ignore warnings for only one statement in this way.

Comment: You mean "curlies" or "block". "Closure" is something very different.

Comment: Thanks, my english not the best one. I will use 'block' onwards.

Answer (score -2):

`WWW::Mechanize` is a proper subclass of `LWP::UserAgent` and you can also use any of `LWP::UserAgent`'s methods.

```
my $content = $mech->decoded_content();#
if (utf8::is_utf8($content)) {
    binmode STDOUT,':utf8';
} else {
    binmode STDOUT,':raw';
}
print $content;

please explain where it use
```